# Ассоциация расширения файлов

Tags: delphi

Регестрирую своё расширение файла с помощью вот этой процедуры:

```
 procedure Registration( FileType,        // Тип файла (расширение)
                        FileTypeName,    // Имя
                        Description,     // Описание
                        ExecCommand,     // Путь к запускному файлу
                        Index: string ); // Индекс иконки
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
   if ( FileType = '' ) or ( FileTypeName = '' ) or
      ( ExecCommand = '' ) then Exit;
   if FileType[1] <> '.' then FileType := '.' + FileType;
   if Description = '' then Description := FileTypeName;
   reg := TRegistry.Create;
   with Reg do
   begin
      RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
      OpenKey( FileType, true );
      WriteString( '', FileTypeName );
      CloseKey;
      OpenKey( FileTypeName, true );
      WriteString( '', Description );
      CloseKey;
      OpenKey( FileTypeName + '\DefaultIcon', true );
      WriteString( '', ExecCommand + ', ' + Index );
      CloseKey;
      OpenKey( FileTypeName + '\Shell\Open\Command', true );
      WriteString( '', ExecCommand + ' %1' );
   end;
   reg.Free;

end;
```

Добавил ещё одну иконку для файлов в ресурсы программы с помощью менеджера ресурсов.

Делаю идентификатор ресурса 1.

Регистрирую так:

```
    Registration( '.test',        // Тип файла (расширение)
                        'Proga.exe',    // Имя
                        'test',     // Описание
                        extractfilepath(Application.ExeName)+'Proga.exe',     // Путь к запускному файлу
                        '1' ); // Индекс иконки как и индификатор
```

Проблема в том, что в программе тоже меняется иконка на ту, которую я хочу использовать для файлов.

Что я не так делаю и как лучше сделать?

P.S. Я хочу добиться того, чтобы у программы была своя иконка а у файлов - своя...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Windows так и будет: первая иконка в ресурсах считается иконкой приложения. Самый простой путь, не затрагивающий ресурсы в принципе - создать для программы шорткат, в котором назначить другую иконку.